# AUTO Software for ODE's: references or forums?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, math-software, bifurcation

I'm learning the [AUTO software](http://sourceforge.net/projects/auto-07p/) that does [numerical continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_continuation) of ODE's by following these two references:

- The official manual found here [www.dam.brown.edu/.../auto07p.pdf](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/sandsted/auto/auto07p.pdf)
- Lecture notes found at [indy.cs.concordia.ca/auto/notes.pdf](http://indy.cs.concordia.ca/auto/notes.pdf)

The examples are understandable, but going from there to defining your own problem presents a very steep learning curve.

So I'm looking for other good references, or perhaps even an online forum for people using this software. Any suggestions?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning AUTO-07p too, in my experience the best way to define your own problems is editing some demo according to your problem. I actually don't know more references that the official manual, that's one big problem with AUTO, there is not so much documentation. The software XPPAUT http://www.math.pitt.edu/~bard/xpp/xpp.html is another way to run AUTO in a more simple way, maybe you should try it.